# Required Specific Part of string using Jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want Require to Specific Part of string using Jquery or JavaScript?

Example :

```
var name = "jayesh.photo.png";
var name2 = "ruchita.photo.jpeg";
var name3 = "anil.photo.jpg";
```

How to get image extension using Jquery or JS.

I want `ext1 = png,  ext2 = jpeg, ext3 = jpg` ;

Comment: `name.split('.').pop()`

Comment: adeneo comment is best. OP take it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` with `.`(dot) as delimitor and take the last array element after split.

```js
var name = "jayesh.photo.png";
var name2 = "ruchita.photo.jpeg";
var name3 = "anil.photo.jpg";

var nameArray =  name.split('.');
alert(nameArray[nameArray.length-1]);

var name2Array =  name2.split('.');
alert(name2Array[name2Array.length-1]);

var name3Array =  name3.split('.');
alert(name3Array[name3Array.length-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String functions like below:

```
var required_string = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1,name.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this multiple ways:

```
var name = "jayesh.photo.png";

//1
console.log(name.replace(/^.*?\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, "$1"));

//2
console.log(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1, name.length));

//3
var testvar = name.split('.');
console.log(testvar[testvar.length-1]);

//4
console.log(name.split('.').pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could populate an array and loop it:

```
var name = "jayesh.photo.png";
var name2 = "ruchita.photo.jpeg";
var name3 = "anil.photo.jpg";

var photo = [name, name2, name3];
$.each(photo, function(key, value) {
    console.log( "extension = " + value.substring(value.lastIndexOf("."),value.length ) );
});
```